# Can't load Simply Scheme code

Tags: scheme

I'm having trouble with loading the code for the Berkeley Scheme course Simply Scheme, specifically [this](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/downloads/simply/simply.scm) code. I've tested it in many different versions of Scheme. In Chicken, I get this error:

```
#;1> (load "simply.scm")
; loading simply.scm ...

Error: (symbol->string) bad argument type - not a symbol: #<procedure (? wd)>

    Call history:

    <syntax>      (##core#if (empty? x) (##core#begin (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST: " x)) (##core#if (word? x) (......
    <syntax>      (empty? x)
    <syntax>      (##core#begin (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST: " x))
    <syntax>      (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST: " x)
    <syntax>      (##core#if (word? x) (##core#begin (word-first x)) (##core#begin (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST:...
    <syntax>      (word? x)
    <syntax>      (##core#begin (word-first x))
    <syntax>      (word-first x)
    <syntax>      (##core#begin (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST: " x))
    <syntax>      (whoops "Invalid argument to FIRST: " x)
    <syntax>      (##core#undefined)
    <syntax>      (word->string word->string)
    <eval>    (word->string word->string)
    <eval>    (string? wd)
    <eval>    (number? wd)
    <eval>    (symbol->string wd)   <--
```

Just for comparison, Racket gives this error:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.3.
> (load "simply.scm")
simply.scm:20:12: set!: cannot mutate module-required identifier
  in: number->string
  context...:
   /home/hercynian/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

. . . which doesn't seem to be the same thing. This is beyond my rank beginner skills to fathom. Any ideas what's wrong with simply.scm?

Comment: Did you try with Guile?

Comment: It was my first. `In procedure symbol->string: Wrong type argument in position 1 (expecting symbol)`...

Comment: I tested it with guile (2.0.11), chicken's intepreter (4.10.0), and gambit's interpreter (4.2.8) and in all three it seems to load ok... What version are you using? Try either the newer guile, or gambit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work with:

- guile (2.0.11),
- chicken's intepreter (4.10.0),
- gambit's interpreter gsi (4.2.8),
- mit-scheme (9.1.1)

Racket will not do, afaik you'd have to modify this file quite heavily (at least change set! to define and probably wrap it all in module? -- but I'm no racket guy)

Here's what I would do:

1. download this simply.scm file once again, just to be sure (your chicken error suggests somewhere you miss "let", maybe in line 264 (def. of *word*) or 310 (def. of *first*)?),
2. try the above scheme implementations, in case you do get any errors, paste them here,
3. in case you don't have these versions (which would be weird, but I don't know your situation), and are doing the course on your own, try to do it without simply.scm, and any time you find something's missing in your scheme, try to copy only that definition from simply.scm (or modify your code so that it's not needed) -- that's the hardcore way.

Comment: Downloading again seemed to solve it. Not sure what was wrong with my original copy. (Forgot to diff...)

Answer (score 0):

I see from the error that you are using DrRacket IDE or racket binary.

Racketeer and SO-er [Danny Yoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/723947/dyoo) has made a Racket module language to support Simply Scheme in the racket language suite. In Racket with the bottom left dropdown set to "Determine language from source" and replace the definitions window, including the `#lang` line  to the following:

```
#lang planet dyoo/simply-scheme:2

(se (butlast (bf "this"))
    "world")
```

And press <kbd>RUN</kbd>. It will download and install the language and then you'll see the answer `(hi "world")`. The first time around you might see an error, but my experience is that it will go away on a consecutive run.

The definitions will have all the simply scheme features described in the [the documentation](http://www.hashcollision.org/simply-scheme/index.html). Happy hacking!